# Populate view with different values in js

Tags: javascript, html, populate

I am writing a website and need to work with a big data mass. I sort this with special algorithmics and now I want to populate one whole table, but put in different values.

I already have this HTML piece:

```
<div class='main_has_permission' id="main_has_permission">
            <div class='main_padding' id="main_padding">

              <div class="noten_tabelle_permission" id="noten_tabelle_permission">
                <h1 id="member_name"></h1>
                <table id="grades_table" style="width:100%">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Fach</th>
                    <th>mündlich</th>
                    <th>Klausur</th>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The `main_padding` div is the div in which the whole table should be populated.

With the following code, I get the data and call a function to add the values to the table:

```
db.collection("users")
  .doc(el)
  .collection("grades")
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      const data = doc.data();
      addToTable("grade_table" + table_number, doc.id, data.mdl, data.klu);
    });
  });
```

Finally here is the function who adds the values to the table:

```
function addToTable(table_name, subject, mdl, klu) {

  var subject_name = getSubjectByNumber(subject);
  var short_subject = getSubjectShortByNumber(subject);

      //Zeile erstellen

      var y = document.createElement([short_subject]);
      y.setAttribute("id", [short_subject]);
      document.getElementById([table_name]).appendChild(y);

      //Spalten in einer Zeile

      var y = document.createElement("TR");
      y.setAttribute("id", [short_subject]);

      //Spalten in einer Zeile

      var cE = document.createElement("TD");
      var tE = document.createTextNode([subject_name]);
      cE.appendChild(tE);
      y.appendChild(cE);

      var a = document.createElement("TD");
      var b = document.createTextNode([mdl]);
      a.appendChild(b);
      y.appendChild(a);

      var c = document.createElement("TD");
      var d = document.createTextNode([klu]);
      c.appendChild(d);
      y.appendChild(c);


      document.getElementById("grades_table").appendChild(y);
}
```

Now...How to populate the table by putting in different values? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with your problem? What do you mean by wanting to "populate the table by putting in different values?"

Comment: @AndrewLohr Populate the table which I already write but with different content in the rows